# Puppet removes packages while installing "lsscsi"

Tags: debian, puppet, package-management

We wanted to install the "lsscsi" package on all our Linux Servers and build a manifest for it:

```
# pack_lsscsi.pp

class common::pack_lsscsi  {

        case $operatingsystem {
                RedHat, CentOS, Debian: {
                        package { 'lsscsi':
                                ensure  => 'installed',
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

The "lsscsi" Package has only "libc6" as a dependency - so a no brainer at all. All went fine on our Red Hat and CentOS servers, but some Debian systems went crazy. Puppet removed between 10 and 180 packages, like on this one:

```
Sep 17 10:46:06 cacti01 puppet-agent[28008]
(/Stage[main]/Common::Pack_lsscsi/Package[lsscsi]/ensure) change from purged
to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/aptitude -y -o
DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install lsscsi' returned 255: Reading package
lists...#012Building dependency tree...#012Reading state information...#012Reading
extended state information...#012Initializing package states...#012Writing extended
state information...#012The following NEW packages will be installed:#012  lsscsi
#012The following packages will be REMOVED:#012  alien{u} apt-file{u} ash{u} at{u}
autopoint{u} biff{u} bin86{u} bison{u} #012  bwidget{u} checkpolicy{u} cramfsprogs{u}
curl{u} dbus{u} debhelper{u} #012  deborphan{u} dhcp-client{u} doc-linux-de{u}
dosfstools{u} dselect{u} #012  ethtool{u} fdutils{u} finger{u} flex{u} flip{u}
gcc-3.4-base{u} gdb{u} #012  gdbserver{u} gettext{u} gnu-efi{u} gnupg-doc{u}
hicolor-icon-theme{u} #012  html2text{u} hwdata{u} ifenslave{u} ifenslave-2.6{u}
intltool-debian{u} #012  iptraf{u} joe{u} kernel-package{u} language-env{u}
lgtoclnt{u} #012  libappconfig-perl{u} libapt-pkg-perl{u} libatk1.0-0{u}
libatk1.0-data{u} #012  libaudit0{u} libavahi-client3{u} libavahi-common-data{u}
#012  libavahi-common3{u} libbeecrypt6{u} libbind9-50{u} #012  libcompress-raw-zlib-
perl{u} libcompress-zlib-perl{u} #012  libconfig-file-perl{u} libcroco3{u} libcrypt-
ssleay-perl{u} libcups2{u} #012  libcurl3{u} libdb1-compat{u} libdb4.2{u} libdbus-1-
3{u} #012  libdigest-hmac-perl{u} libdigest-sha1-perl{u} libdirectfb-1.0-0{u} #012
libdns58{u} libdrm-intel1{u} libdrm-radeon1{u} libdrm2{u} libelf1{u} #012  libfam0{u}
libfam0c102{u} libfile-remove-perl{u} libfont-afm-perl{u} #012  libfs6{u} libgl1-mesa-
dri{u} libgl1-mesa-glx{u} libglade2-0{u} #012  libglu1-mesa{u} libgtk2.0-0{u}
libgtk2.0-bin{u} libgtk2.0-common{u} #012  libhtml-format-perl{u} libhtml-parser-
perl{u} libhtml-tagset-perl{u} #012  libhtml-tree-perl{u} libice6{u} libident{u}
libio-compress-base-perl{u} #012  libio-compress-zlib-perl{u} libio-stringy-perl{u}
Sep 17 10:46:09 cacti01 puppet-agent[28008]: Finished catalog run in 54.68 seconds
```

Any idea how that could happen?

Thomas

Comment: Which Debian release do you use? Maybe this is an older release (like lenny) which needs to be upgraded to a current release.

Comment: Or maybe the apt sources or pinning got configured incorrectly.

Comment: We use Debian Squeeze. /etc/apt/sources.list identical on all servers, pointing to our own Debian Mirror.

This happend to about 1/10 of all our Debian servers. That's what puzzles me.

Comment: can you show what an "apt-cache policy lsscsi" shows, as well as "cat /etc/debian_release". Also a pastbin of /var/log/dpkg.log may help show the history of package changes on the system helping to track down the cause.

Comment: I find it helps with debugging to try to the aptitude command outside of puppet with simulate/verbose to see the actual output from apt.  "aptitude --verbose --simulate install lsscsi"

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer the `aptitude` provider over `apt`? Trying the latter may be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `aptitude` likes to remove packages that it thinks are unused.  `aptitude` tracks every program it installs and classifies as either "manual" or "automatic".  "Manual" packages are ones that explicitly request for installation.  "Automatic" packages are ones that you didn't specifically request but that were installed as dependencies.  For example, `aptitude install irssi` will install irssi, but also a host of libraries including libncurses, lbperl, lbtinfo, libval, and others.  If at some point you remove irssi and it was the only installed package that needed some of those libraries, `aptitude` will remove the unneeded automatically-installed libraries, too.

Unfortunately, it used to be the case that `aptitude` and `apt-get` didn't play well together and packaged installed by `apt-get` would often be regarded by `aptitude` as automatically-installed and, thus, candidates for deletion.  Newer versions of `apt-get` work much better in concert with `aptitude`, but this problem manifested at a time when these problems existed.

If, for some reason, you're still getting this behavior now, there are a couple of options.  The simplest would be to just change to using the `apt` provider for Puppet's `package` type.  That would completely sidestep any confusion `aptitude` has about which packages it ought to remove.

If you need to keep using the `aptitude` provider, you'll need to fix `aptitude`'s ideas about what's in use.  Run `aptitude dist-upgrade` and look at every package it wants to remove.  For each one you know you want to keep, run `aptitude unmarkauto <package-name>` (e.g. `aptitude unmarkauto apt-file curl`).  Then make sure you only use `aptitude` for package installations from that point onwards.

In my experience, the only things that `aptitude` does better than current versions of `apt-get` are interactive: the curses interface and the ability to modify the set of package installs/removals in the middle of a command line session.  Puppet doesn't need any of the interactive features, so you really should be okay just using the `apt` provider.